# Editing cell value changes its formatting

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates, google-sheets-cell-format

1. Enter the value `18/04/2020 08:10:00` in a sell.
2. Set the formatting of the sell to `Hour(1):Minute(01)`

   - Actual value `18/04/2020 08:10:00`
   - Display value: `8:10`
3. Edit the value of the sell to become `18/04/2020 08:11:00`

   - Actual value `18/04/2020 08:11:00`
   - **Expected** Display value: `8:11`
   - **Expected** Formatting: `Hour(1):Minute(01)` (as set earlier)
   - **Current** Display value: `18/04/2020 08:11:00`
   - **Current** Formatting: `Day(05)/Month(08)/Year(1930) Hour(01):Minute(01):Second(01)`

Answer (score 1):

You said:

> 1. Formatting for Column A is set to: `Hour(1):Minute(01)`
> 2. The values in that column are like: `1054496:09` (Timestamp with date)

I am not able to reproduce your formatting.
If one uses `Hour(1):Minute(01)` to change the timestamp `16/04/2020 08:09:00` to `1054496:09`, Google sheets automatically converts the cell to `8:09` while inside the cell one reads `16/04/2020 08:09:00` or `04/16/2020 08:09:00` (depending on the locale of the sheet).
In any case...

### Solution

1. **Copy the value** of any of your converted timestamps in the format `1054398:09` and **paste it in an unformatted cell**. The value in the cell will be `1054398:09:00.000` , while it will be shown as `1054398:09`. **Do NOT manually format the cell**.
2. Use the `Paint format` *(Roller)* tool from the menu and format the other cells. **Do NOT manually format the cells**.

**These formatted cells will stay** in the format `1054398:09` no matter the changes.

```
+---------------------+-------------------------------------+
| 18/04/2020 08:10:00 | Formatted as Timestamp/Date time    |
+---------------------+-------------------------------------+
| 8:10                | Formatted as Hour(1):Minute(01)     |
+---------------------+-------------------------------------+
| 1054544:10:00       | UNFORMATTED/Formatted as "nothing"  |
+---------------------+-------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I'm really so sorry. I made a mistake. the format is not 1054496:09 I copy pasted value only to some other random sell and this appeared so I thought this is the basic format for timestamp. I updated my question.

Comment: _""_. I don't see it updated. Also, since the answer to your original question is correct, I would suggest accepting it and posting a new question. Otherwise users will be confused.

Comment: Refresh your page.

Comment: I can see it now. Still. As mentioned before -since now your question is completely different- _"I would suggest accepting it and posting a new question. Otherwise users will be confused"_.

Comment: But I do not understand what you understanding of my problem was, this is not a completely different question. The only problem was that I mistakenly thought that `1054544:10:00` was the definition of a timestamp which was not the case. However I had ever written in parenthesis that I meant timestamp with date by that. I do not see this as a different question. I see this as a valid question and the other one as an invalid misguiding question.